# Find the nodes which are coming in continuety and then add a parent tag to them xslt1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have a xml like below:

```
<root>
    <p>some text</p>
    <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="some-link" rel="nofollow">link</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <li>tag with parent as root</li>
    <li>another li tag with parent as root</li>
    <li>another li tag with parent as root</li>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <li>some text in li.</li>
    <li>another li tag with parent as root</li>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <li>some text in li.</li>
    <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a>
</root>
```

Desired output: I want to add a parent to the all li tags which don't have any parent and also I want to add the li tags into a common parent if there are more than one li tags coming in continuety.

```
 <root>
        <p>some text</p>
        <ol>
          <li>
             <a href="some-link" rel="nofollow">link</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
        <ul>
          <li>tag with parent as root</li>
          <li>another li tag with parent as root</li>
          <li>another li tag with parent as root</li>
        </ul>
        <p>some more text</p>
        <ul>
          <li>some text in li.</li>
          <li>another li tag with parent as root</li>
        </ul>
        <p>some more text</p>
        <ul>
          <li>some text in li.</li>
        </ul>
    </root>
```

I tried various things but doesn't work. Thanks in advance

```
  <xsl:template match="li[not(parent::ol) and not(parent::ul)]">
  <ul>
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </ul>
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="li[not(parent::ol) and not(parent::ul)]">
  <xsl:for-each select="root/li">
        <ul><xsl:value-of select="."/></ul>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="li[not(parent::ol) and not(parent::ul)]">
        <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable in XSLT 1 with a key, a rather convoluted one, but doing the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="li-group" match="*[not(self::ol | self::ul)]/li[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li]]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::li[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li])][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::ol | self::ul)]/li[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li])]">
    <ul>
      <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('li-group', generate-id())"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::ol | self::ul)]/li[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Other options are sibling recursion.

Comment: can we get the same output with apply-templates instead of copy-of. Please suggest changes if possible. Because of copy-of I’m getting other issues

Comment: @rajatsethi, ask a new question then detailing the problems. Or read up on modes and push the "group" of nodes the `key()` call gives you through templates in another mode.

Comment: here is the details for that particular scenerio https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71912673/some-apply-templates-are-not-working-as-expected-in-xslt-1