# Some apply-templates are not working as expected in xslt 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My input:

```
<li>
     <span font-color="#2b91bf">FIRST FACT</span>
  </li>
  <li>
     <span font-color="#2b91bf">SECOND FACT</span>
  </li>
  <li>
     <span font-color="#2b91bf">THIRD FACT</span>
     <b>hi</b>
  </li>
  <b> bold text <b>
```

Desired output:

```
<ul><li>
         <span style="color:#2574A9;">FIRST FACT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span style="color:#2574A9;">SECOND FACT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span style="color:#2574A9;">THIRD FACT</span>
         <strong>hi</strong>
      </li>
</ul>
<strong>bold text</strong>
```

Output which i'm getting: `<b> tag` inside the li are not converted to strong and also font-color attribute also not converted into style but the attributes or tags which are outside the li tag are converted properly. Is this because of `<xsl:copy-of>`?

```
<ul><li>
         <span font-color="#2b91bf">FIRST FACT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span font-color="#2b91bf">SECOND FACT</span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span font-color="#2b91bf">THIRD FACT</span>
         <b>hi</b>
      </li></ul>
      <b> bold text <b>
```

I'm using below xsl to process the  above snippet.

```
<xsl:template match="b">
        <strong>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </strong>

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <span>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-color, '#4f5967')">color:#4D4F52;</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-color, '#acb3bf')">color:#6B6E70;</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-color, '#2b91bf')">color:#2574A9;</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-color, '#0077a7')">color:#21219A;</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-face, 'baskerville')"
                        >font-family:'EB Garamond', serif;</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-face, 'courier')"
                        >font-family:'Space Mono', monospace;</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-face, 'museo')"
                        >font-family:'Work Sans', sans-serif;</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(./@font-face, 'proxima')"
                        >font-family:Overlock, sans-serif;</xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
<—- below lines of code will add ul tag as parent to those li tags which neither has it’s parent as ol nor ul —->
 <xsl:key name="li-group" match="*[not(self::ol | self::ul)]/li[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li]]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::li[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li])][1])"/>


  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::ol | self::ul)]/li[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li])]">
    <ul>
      <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('li-group', generate-id())"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(self::ol | self::ul)]/li[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::li]]"/>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: I added small comment lines inside xsl. I hope it clears the working. Will try to be more clear, direct and precise in next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<xsl:copy-of select=". | key('li-group', generate-id())"/>` you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select=". | key('li-group', generate-id())" mode="li"/>` and then

```
<xsl:template match="li" mode="li">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```